# List all championships that were in progress in a month/year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve this select statement. 
My problem is list all championships that were in progress in a month and year.

For exemple, I wanna to list

all championships that were in progress in march, 2005.

I have this columns:

Table: Championships
(id_champ, name, startDate, endDate).

How Can I list all championships that were in progress in March, 2005?

I'm trying this:

```
SELECT * from championships 
where (month(startDate) <= 3 
and year(startDate)<=2005) 
and (month(startDate)<=3 and year(endDate)<=2005
```

Anyone here knows a correct way or best way to solve it?

Comment: I will create a stored procedure using one parameter (the date to check, for example 01/01/2014). First you get the month and the year in two variables then you add your SQL select statement by including @ Month and @ year variables (I will use between instruction). It will be more efficient and you only need to use one parameter. To use it : EXEC sp_find_championships_in_progress <dateToCheck>.

Answer (score 2):

To catch anything active in March 2005:

```
select
*
from
championships
where
year(enddate) = 2005
and 3 between month(startdate) and month(enddate).
```

Comment: What if a championship ran past 2005? This select would not capture that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select *
From championships
where (startdate < `2005/4/1`) AND (enddate > '2005/2/28')
```

This will find any championship that started before April 1, 2005, and ended anytime after February 28, 2005.

Using dateadd would actually be best, to take care of leap day and such. So consider:

```
Select *
From championships
where (startdate < dateadd(1, mm, `2005/3/1`)) AND (enddate > dateadd(-1, dd, '2005/3/1' ) )
```

Now you don't have to have code calculate the final day of the month for the startdate term, nor calculate the final day of the month for the enddate.